# Forms and Threading - Form does not show up

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, forms

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim Form2Show As New Thread(AddressOf Form2Thread)
    Form2Show.Start()

    Main()

End Sub

Public Sub Form2Thread()
    Label1.Text = "Loading..."
    Me.Show()
End Sub
```

What I am trying to do is to start a new thread, which causes a form to show up (in this case just a window that says loading), and then continue on to execute the main subroutine.

I'm not that familiar with threading, so I do not know if I am doing this right, but this is based on what I have found on the internet. Also I want to note that this is running inside of the Form2 class, and Form2_Load is the first thing that the program executes.

If anyone has any suggestions or corrections, I would love to hear them! Thank you very much!

EDIT: I forgot to say what was happening. The form instantly closes when running the compiled exe, and does not show at all when stepping through (although I don't know how stepping through deals with multiple threads). Also, I have another form later in the project which also opens and instantly closes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show the Form1, instead of Form2 again (with the Me.Show() you are reffering to the same Form (Form2) again.

```
    Public Sub Form2Thread()
        Label1.Text = "Loading..."
        Form1.Show() '//instead of Me.Show()
    End Sub
```

Comment: This code was written inside the Form2 class, so when I try to used Form2.Show(), it will not compile, and it asks for Me.Show instead. Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: Ah sorry i made the same error like you did :) You need to replace the Form2.Show() with Form1.Show()

Comment: Maybe I did a bad job of explaining... I am trying to get form 2 to show, not form1. Form 1 is used later in the program. At the start of the program, I just need form 2. Thanks again for spending time on your answer :)

Comment: Ok, i think i figured out the problem. Your thread is trying to access a module (the label) that is outside of it's permissions (while trying out you code, i noticed the thread can't access the Form either).             [This project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31985/Updating-the-UI-from-a-thread-The-simplest-way) describes the problem quite well. Your thread is simply not allowed to update any of the Form2.

Comment: That looks pretty good. I'll check that out and come back once I figure out if it will work. Thank you very much for your help!